# Firefox cell border rendering bug when adding rows

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table

I have a table with collapsed borders. Some cells have borders around them. When I add rows to this table, suddenly all the cells in a given column get borders in Firefox.

The CSS is simple enough

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.has-errors {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Here is a JSBin to illustrate the issue: https://jsbin.com/jopaxoyesu/edit?html,css,js,output

Clicking the document adds rows. If you click once, it's fine. Click again, and suddenly all the cells in that column will have left and right borders. This only happens in Firefox.

What workaround is there for this?

I can't use border separate.
Using 'outline' doubles the borders and looks bad.
I'd prefer not to force a restyle as I'm concerned about performance. Anything else I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use outline instead of border if you want to keep border-collapse

```js
$(document).on('click', function() {
  $('table').append('<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>')
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.has-errors {
   outline: 2px solid red;
   -moz-outline: 2px solid red;
   outline-offset:-1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
 
 <table cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr>  
      <td >1</td>
      <td class="has-errors">2</td>
      <td class="has-errors">3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: That is very clever way of using outline-offset, good to know.

Comment: outline-offset isn't supported in IE11, but I think I can live with those users getting a mildly uglier experience. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know you have mentioned your preference of not restyling, however the only remedy to this issue I have found so far was to remove border-collapse.

```
table {
/* REMOVED border-collapse*/
}

.has-errors {
    outline: 2px solid red;
    -moz-outline: 2px solid red;
    outline-offset:-1px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide correct formatted answer by correcting question's code can help user to understand answer better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is border-collapse, but if you use instead cellspacing="0" on table  and a little trick in css (where you remove the left border if there are 2 or more `.has-errors` near), it works also with firefox!

```js
$(document).on('click', function() {
  $('table').append('<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>')
});
```

```css
.has-errors {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.has-errors + .has-errors{
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
 
 <table cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr>  
      <td >1</td>
      <td class="has-errors">2</td>
      <td class="has-errors">3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```